# Gradle compile error

Tags: android-studio

I´m getting this error running my app

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Anyone knows how can i fix it?

Comment: Is that all of the error? I think you omitted some part of it.

Comment: @Daniel Cheng yes it was all the error, but nevermind i just exit android studio and start it again and the error was gone lol